# Duplicate/Copy same file N times

Tags: r, file, automation, directory, duplicates

I have an R file that is stored in a directory on my computer. I would like to create 10 duplicates of this R file in an automatized way. The 10 duplicates of this R file should be stored in the same directory and each of them should have a different file name.

**Example:**

My working directory:

```
getwd()
# [1] "D:/Example Directory"
```

With the [dir function](https://statistical-programming.com/dir-r-function-example/), I can extract the names of all files that are stored in this directory:

```
path <- getwd()
dir(path)
# "1.R"
```

The only file in this directory is the R file `1.R`. I would like to duplicate this R file 10 times. The duplicates should be called `2.R`, `3.R`, `4.R` and so on.

This could be easily done with a manually conducted copy/paste. However, since I have to duplicate the file many times, I'm looking for an automatized way in R.

**Question: How could I duplicate this R file in an automatized way?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `file.copy` function that needs original file name as first argument and accepts vector of wanted file names as second argument.

```
file.copy(dir(getwd()), paste0(2:10, ".R"))
```

PS: Make sure that in current directory there's only one file in the beginning.

---

Or you can use a safe solution with `list.files` and `file.exists`:

```
nFiles <- 10
myFile <- list.files(pattern = "\\d.R")
for(i in seq_len(nFiles)) {
   wantedFile <- sub("\\d", i, myFile)
   if (!file.exists(wantedFile)) {
      file.copy(myFile, wantedFile)
   }
}
```